# Can qgis cooperate with phpmyadmin?

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, mysql

I have database in myadmin with column for long. and lat. informations.

Is there a way to connect qgis with myadmin?

Or what type of database I must create if I want that each row repesented a point on map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phpmyadmin is no database system. It is a administration tool for MySQL databases.

MySQL databases are supported by QGIS (using [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mysql.html)). However you will have to convert your lat/lon information into a spatial column. You find the required information in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/populating-spatial-columns.html).

And because you asked *what type of database is supported*: [there is a wide variety](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS#supported-vector-formats-include).